# Finding permutations of a list using insertion of element in Prolog

Tags: prolog

For an assignment I'm asked to define a permutation function in two different ways; one making use of `delete(X,L1,L2)` which is true iff `L1=L2\X`, and one making use of `insert(X,L1,L2)` which is true iff `L2-L1 = [X]`.

So far I've gotten everything working except the permutation generator which uses the insert function. My current code:

```
join([],L,L).
join([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]) :-
    join(L1,L2,L3).

delete(X,L1,L2) :-
    join(L3,[X|L4],L1),
    join(L3,L4,L2).

insert(X,[],[X]).
insert(X,L1,L2) :-
    delete(X,L2,L1).

permutationDelete([],[]).
permutationDelete([H|L1],L2) :-
    delete(H,L2,L3),
    permutationDelete(L1,L3).

permutationInsert([X|L1],L2) :-
    insert(X,L1,L2),
```

But I can't seem to find a workable algorithm to make use of the insert function. Any tips?

Comment: Your `permutationInsert/2` seems to be missing a recursive call and a base case. Why do you need `insert(X, [], [X])`? Doesn't `delete(X, [X], [])` succeed? By the way, Prolog doesn't have *functions*, it has *predicates*. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: I just copy pasted the code I had. That predicate is not finished yet. I need the insert because it's part of the assignment I'm asked to make, delete succeeds without problem.

Comment: The `insert(X, [], [X])` clauses is redundant, though, since your other clause will already succeed with those arguments. It may cause you to get some solutions twice. Without seeing the rest of your permutation code, and without an explanation as to exactly why what you have doesn't work, it's difficult to comment on what may be wrong.

Comment: The `permutationInsert/2` predicate should perform the exact same function as the `permutationDelete/2` predicate, but use `insert/3` as opposed to `delete/3`. I have not been able to think of a way to do this, which is what this question is for. So in short: How can I write a permutation predicate similar that gives the same results as `permutationDelete/2` but uses the `insert/3` predicate?

Comment: Your should be able to just copy your `permutationDelete/2` and replace `delete(H, L2, L3)` with `insert(H, L3, L2)` as long as you have properly defined them. Bte, I highly recommend avoiding reusing predicate names that Prolog already has defined. You can get unexpected results. This applies to the names `insert` and `delete`.

Comment: @lurker I do indeed use different names but they're in another language so this makes it a little more clear. I tried what you said, and though it does work, it also gives every permutation twice. e.g. `permutationDelete(X,[a,b,c])` leads to: `X = [a, b, c]; 
X = [a, b, c]; 
X = [a, c, b]; 
X = [a, c, b]; 
X = [b, a, c]; 
X = [b, a, c]; 
X = [b, c, a]; 
X = [b, c, a]; 
X = [c, a, b]; 
X = [c, a, b]; 
X = [c, b, a]; 
X = [c, b, a]`

Comment: It gives every permutation twice because of what I said before about your definition for `insert`. Read my prior comment on that again.

Comment: Hah, now that comment makes a lot more sense!  Thanks for your help! :)